# How to use user_id from a label in another form

Tags: c#, sql, function, label, userid

I am trying to create a function GetUserID() which returns the userID, which I have inserted  into a label so I can use it in other forms.

But when I try to convert the label to int32 the label always seems to be empty. I think its because of where the function is placed in my code.

See:

```
private void Loginbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var LoginFunction = new LoginFunction();

        var DataTable = new DataTable();

        DataTable = LoginFunction.Login(Usernametxt.Text.Trim(), Passwordtxt.Text.Trim());
        int UserID = Convert.ToInt32(DataTable.Rows[0]["USER_ID"]);

        if (DataTable.Rows.Count == 1)
        {
            CalculatorMain calculatorMain = new CalculatorMain();
            MainMenu mainMenu = new MainMenu();
            UserIDlbl.Text = Convert.ToString(UserID);
            MessageBox.Show("ID = " + UserID);

            this.Hide();
            mainMenu.Show();


        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You entered the wrong username or password");
        }




    }
    public int GetUserID()
    {
        int UserID;


        if (Int32.TryParse(UserIDlbl.Text, out UserID))
        {
            UserID = Convert.ToInt32(UserIDlbl.Text);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error, Label for UserID could not be parsed");
        }

        return UserID;



    }
```

I'm not sure where else I can put this function to get it to work.

Here is the code to call the function which is used in a separate form.

```
private void WorkoutHistoryForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Login login = new Login();



        int UserId = login.GetUserID();


        this.sETSTableAdapter.Fill(this.gymDataSet.SETS, UserId);



    }
```

I keep thinking there must be a better way to do this instead of storing the UserID in a label but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a public class with a public field to store the UserID.

For example. let's say you have the UserID in an int variable as you have described. Now let's say you have created a public static class called `Common` defined with a public static field of type int called `ID`.

You can now store the UserID in the static field of the class:

```
Common.ID = UserID
```

Later, when you want to access the UserID from some other form, just do this:

```
string UserID = Common.ID
```

Easy peasey.

Of course, you don't need to do this in a *separate* class... your form itself is a class, and you can create your public field there, and call it like

```
Form1.UserID
```

Or whatever the name of your original form is where you captured the UserID...

Comment: How would I get the userID? currently I get it from the data table after I call the function with username and password as arguments but I don’t want to execute that code twice. And I’m not sure how to return two types of data in a function

Comment: This was assuming you have retrieved the UserID up front, as you are already doing. My suggestion is to store it in a class property (field), instead of storing it in a label on a form. I'm not sure I understand why you would need to return two values from a function. But if you find the need for that, there are 2 good options: 1. Use a class to store both properties and access them there when you need them. 2. You can use Out arguments as parameters to a function if you want more than one return value. I prefer #1.